# How Can I Detect My Character's Nearest Enemy?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to be able to control this when my player is close to the enemy. It's partially happening but I have a problem and I don't know why it's happening.

There are 2 enemy objects on the stage. The player notices one of them when he approaches, but nothing happens when he approaches the other.

This is my codes;

```
private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("UpdateTarget", 0f, 0.5f);
}

private void UpdateTarget()
{
    
    Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

    foreach(GameObject enemy in Target)
    {
        float distanceToEnemy = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);

        if(distanceToEnemy < range)
        {
            closeEnemy = enemy;
        }
        else
        {
            closeEnemy = null;
        }
        
    }

}
```

And this is what happened; / **This picture is gif.**

**NOT: All targets have same tag.**

[image]

Comment: you seem to have only asked which is within range, and got the last one, you dont seem to have considered if there are more inside the range, to bother to tell which is actually closest

Comment: Kindly consider using [Vector3.sqrMagnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html) instead of using [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) to add a bit of optimization for these calculations.